# Open file as string instead of bytes in python

Tags: python, python-requests, icalendar

I am working on a project that reads a url which contains an ICS file (icalendar). Instead of reading it as a string it prints as bytes need some advice on this.

```
import requests
url = "http://ical.keele.ac.uk/index.php/ical/ical/15021113"
c = requests.get(url)
c.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
print(c.content)
```

Expected return

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
```

Actual return

```
b"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\rVERSION:2.0\rPRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\rBEGIN:VEVENT\r
```

I have tried using the ics file directly and works without any problems but when I request from url it doesnt work. Thanks

Comment: Use `c.text` instead of `c.content`?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Tried that made it worst =( instead of getting 300lines of codes i got one line of code only and it is jumbled up code.

Comment: It's the same content except now it's a string instead of bytes.  https://bpaste.net/show/cc22717aacbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delirious Lettuce is right, just use text:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

```
import requests
url = "http://ical.keele.ac.uk/index.php/ical/ical/15021113"
c = requests.get(url)
#c.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
#print(c.content)
print(c.text[:10])
```

results in

```
BEGIN:VCAL
```

(3.6.1 32 bit windows)